# No wi-fi on 20.04

Tags: wireless

So I get this is a very common problem but after numerous videos and tutorials I'm still stuck.

I think the issue might involve something with disabling secure boot but that doesn't seem to be an option for me as I get a message stating "EFI variables are not supported on this system".

I'm still quite a newb but I think I've installed the realtek driver but it doesn't seem to be the one that's active and nothing else is showing up on the Additional Drivers in the Software Updater except a reference to my Nvidia video driver.

Any additional insight?

Update: in response to chipset request here is what I have...

```
    :~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0084]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
07:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP [1022:1485]
```

Comment: No, it's not very common. Since you have been through all those tutorials, you likely have your WiFi chipset model number  (examples: BCM43142 or RTL8125) handy. Enter it in the Search box at the top of this page. Somebody has probably already written a tutorial for your specific hardware.

Comment: Let's find out your chipset with the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Next, edit your question to add the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.